# How can I encrypt my whole personal user folder on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, encryption

I share my computer with other people who also have administrative rights on this PV. To avoid giving them access to my personal data, like recent history, Dropbox content, and so on, I'd like to encrypt my whole user folder.

Notice that it wouldn't be enough to use a PBA-method, because others should be able to boot this computer, too. Also, encryption of sub-folders wouldn't be enough. I may install a new tool which stores important data in a new, not encrypted folder, which I will not recognize.

Comment: TrueCrypt or Bitlocker will do exactly this.

Comment: If you're using Pro version, EFS will do nicely